# CSS Position: relative and absolute issue

Tags: html, css, css-position

You can see my layout prototype on Design Prototype.

I have two : Header and Container. Header area must be placed above the container.
Header has two child elements: Logo DIV and Logo-Title DIV. Their positions being rated to parent [Header DIV]. 
So, I set position of header to relative and children (Logo and Logo-Title) to absolute.

But after it, Container didn't place under header area!
When i remove absolute position from Logo DIV and Logo-TITLE DIV, The Container is OK! but i can align logo and logo-title from parent(Header).

Why? Container isn't child of Header!
How can fix it?

Thanks.

[Design Prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJdQZ.jpg)

```css
@charset "utf-8";

body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 980px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#header{
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 154px;
}

#logo{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    width: 123px;
    height: 146px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: 4px;
}

#logo-title {
    position: absolute;
    color: darkblue;
    font-size: 16pt;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 60px;
}

#container {
    background-color: white;
    height: 600px;
    width: 980px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo"/>
            <div id="logo-title">Logo-Title</div>
        </div>
        <div id="container"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `<div id="logo"></div>` instead of `<div id="logo"/>` - div comes always in pair

Comment: Also try inspecting the element in the browser. Key F12. Then you would see that the container was child of header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single tag closure used on your `logo` doesn't work on div element so I changed it like this

```
<div id="logo"></div>
```

*Colored your `container` to `red` temporary, so one can see that it renders correct now*

```css
@charset "utf-8";

body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 980px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#header{
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 154px;
}

#logo{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    width: 123px;
    height: 146px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: 4px;
}

#logo-title {
    position: absolute;
    color: darkblue;
    font-size: 16pt;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 60px;
}

#container {
    background-color: red;
    height: 600px;
    width: 980px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="logo-title">Logo-Title</div>
  </div>
  <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your  `logo` div has not correct syntax  , closed always div with close div tag like this `<div id="logo"></div>`